# Issue with the solution of a integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

it's  been a while since the last time I used mathematica so i am quite rusty with the syntax

I was trying to calculate the integral of the following function of the cosmological scale factor a ( which is real and <=1):

$$\int_a^1  \frac{2 a^2 w_0-2 a w_0-a w_a+w_0+w_a}{2 a^2-2 a+1}$$

so  I  naively tried with  a definite integral with a as lower bound

```
Integrate[(w0 - 2 a w0 + 2 a^2 w0 + wa - a wa)/(1 - 2 a + 2 a^2), {a, a, 1}, Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals]
```

and I got a huuuge solution which I think it's clearly wrong

> ConditionalExpression[
> 1/8 (-8 (-1 + a) w0 + (1 + I) [Pi] wa + (1 +
> I) wa (2 I (ArcTan[(-1 + a)/a] - Log[1 - (1 + I) a]) +
> Log[1 + 2 (-1 + a) a])), 0 < a < 1]

then I  defined a function

```
uff[a_] = 
 Integrate[(w0 - 2 a* w0 + 2 a^2 *w0 + wa - a *wa)/(1 - 2 a + 2 a^2), 
  a, Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals]

uff[1] - uff[a]
```

and i got a more reasonable result

> w0 - a w0 + ([Pi] wa)/8 + 1/2 wa ArcTan[1 - 2 a] +
> 1/4 wa Log[1 - 2 a + 2 a^2]

My question is: why the 2 different results and what's the best way for these kind of integrals?

thanks

Comment: What version are you using? In my version (11.1.1 for Mac OS X) the following command `Assuming[Element[A | w0 | wa, Reals] && 0 < A < 1, 
 Integrate[(w0 - 2 a w0 + 2 a^2 w0 + wa - a wa)/(1 - 2 a + 2 a^2), {a, A, 1}]]` yield the desired output, i.e., $\frac{1}{8} \left(-8 A \text{w0}+2 \text{wa} \log (2 (A-1) A+1)+4 \text{wa} \tan ^{-1}(1-2 A)+8 \text{w0}+\pi  \text{wa}\right)$

Comment: @yarchik uhm, I am on the smartphone now, but I think it's 11.Something

Comment: ArcTan[x]== I/2  (Log[1-I x] - Log[1+ I x])